# codeigniter variable segments

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm having a problem with codeigniter segments.

Im looking for something like this where my controller is `contacts` and the action is `list`:

```
localhost/index.php/contacts/list/limit/10/offset/100/orderBy/postalCode/search/john/
```

This way I can mix my parameters up, they dont have to be in that specific order, or I can leave them out all together, for instance:

```
localhost/index.php/contacts/list/search/john/
```

How do I get this, because the way I see it, I can only request a segment like so:

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

But segment 3 can cary a offset value or a limit value, or something completely different.

Much appreciated

Comment: I'm sure that this question has been answered before on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=codeigniter+variable+segments

Comment: You should really just enable querystrings in your CI config,  rather than jumping through hoops to implement your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc()` to get the parameters as explained [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).